# A name for PDE systems which are neither under- nor overdetermined?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, terminology, mp.mathematical-physics, differential-operators

The concepts of [overdetermined](http://eom.springer.de/O/o070660.htm) and [underdetermined](http://eom.springer.de/u/u095150.htm) PDE systems are well known. However, all sources I have so far looked into appear to avoid giving any name to PDE systems which are *neither* overdetermined *nor* underdetermined. Is there any reasonably commonly used name for such PDE systems? If possible, please provide the references where the name from your answer is used.

**EDIT:** It was suggested by Igor Khavkine and Robert Bryant that one should consider *formally integrable* systems (which are neither over- nor underdetermined and have no nontrivial compatibility conditions). I like the idea but in my case this term would appear within the discussion of systems which are *completely integrable* (via the inverse scattering transform), and this might confuse the non-expert readers. Is there any sensible way out of this conundrum?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well-posed? Formally integrable? I guess it would depend if you are concerned with purely local or also with global properties.

Comment: @Igor: I am interested in purely local properties.

Comment: @Igor: Thanks for the suggestions, formally integrable sounds interesting. 

Comment: I would be a little wary of the definitions given for "overdetermined" and "underdetermined". Although they work for most examples that arise, they do not in general.

Comment: I'm confused: why formally integrable? May overdetermined or underdetermined systems not also be formally integrabel?

Comment: The links to `eom.springer.de` are broken, but the articles can be found at https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system and https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

determined: Bryant et. al, Exterior Differential Systems, p. 189

Comment: The notion of counting 'number of unknowns' versus 'number of equations' was always meant to be a first crude property of the PDE, it wasn't meant to tell you everything. In fact, this count is only a very rough guide. Even 'determined' systems can fail to have good properties. For example, the equation curl U = F where F is a known vector field in 3-space and U is the unknown vector field, is determined (3 equations for 3 unknowns), but it is not formally integrable (in the usual sense) unless div F = 0

Comment: @Robert Bryant: Dear Professor Bryant, thanks a lot for your comment. May I ask what you would call a system for which BOTH of the following properties hold:
a) the number of unknown functions equals the number of equations; b) there are no nontrivial compatibility conditions?
Is it formally integrable, determined, or what?
   

Comment: A small problem that I have with the term *formally integrable* is that in the context I want to use it will appear together with the term *completely integrable* (through existence of a Lax pair and the inverse scattering transform) which might confuse the non-expert readers. Which is the best way to handle this? Many thanks in advance once again!

Comment: I thought to suggest _involutive determined_, but that isn't quite perfect either. If the integrability conditions are satisfied, then the system will be formally involutive, and also determined, but not quite what you want. 

Comment: I would define a system of linear first order PDE's to be determined if the number of unknowns equals the number of equations *and* can be written in the form $A^i\partial_i u + Bu = f$, where $u$ and $f$ are vector-valued functions, $A^i, B$ are square-matrix-valued functions, and at least one $A^i$ is invertible everywhere.

Comment: "determined" sounds incomplete; "well-determined" sounds nicer (but might mean something different)

Comment: @Deane Yang: that's nice but a bit too restrictive (although this can be fixed if one requires that there exists a change of independent variables after which your property holds). On the other hand, your definition (with or without my modification) can be applied to *quasilinear* systems too.

Comment: @Ben McKay: to me, *involutive determined* doesn't sound bad at all. 

Comment: Well, the salient thing for a 'determined' system, which Deane was alluding to with his definition in the first order quasi-linear case, is whether there are non-characteristic covectors at every point.  This is the necessary and sufficient condition that (locally) the system can be expressed as a system in Cauchy-Kowaleski form (not necessarily of first order).  Thus, another possible phrase you could use is 'determined, of CK-type'.  It's not graceful, but it is clear. I don't think it's a good idea to try to change the accepted definition of 'determined', even if it is naïve.